# php split a string with comma

Tags: php, split

```
$line = "30,[CVS Core] server  dot cvsignore file should be considered by client (1GCC6MB),jean-michel_lemieux@ca.ibm.com,expert,platform-vcm-inbox@eclipse.org";
list($bugId,$bugText,$dupId,$submitId,$submitExpert,$bugFixerId) = split(",", $line);
echo $bugId.",";
echo $submitId.",";
echo $submitExpert.",";
echo $bugFixerId.",";
echo $bugText;
```

Here's my php code but I don't know why it shows that Undefined offset: 5

and here's the result

30,expert,platform-vcm-inbox@eclipse.org,,[CVS Core] server dot cvsignore file should be considered by client (1GCC6MB)

I don't know what happened.

Thanks

Comment: BTW, the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/split) says: `This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.` Use `explode(',', $line);`!

Comment: see the double ,, one of those is empty

Comment: @ComFreek is right, you should explode for that. And using `var_dump(explode(",", $line));` you will see that you only get _five_ parts, but you are trying to list them to _six_ variables.

Comment: the text doesn't have dupId

Comment: str_getcsv() perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

You've got 4 commas in your string, meaning you'll get 5 values after the `split()` call, but are trying to assign the split results to **6** variables. That last one is causing the undefined offset warning. Elimiante the `$bugFixerID` from the `list()` and the warning should go away.

Answer (score 0):

In `$line` you have 5 comma separate values, but list() is expecting 6 values.

```
$line = "30,[CVS Core] server  dot cvsignore file should be considered by client (1GCC6MB),jean-michel_lemieux@ca.ibm.com,expert,platform-vcm-inbox@eclipse.org";

list($bugId,$bugText,$dupId,$submitId,$submitExpert) = split(",", $line);
```

`$bugFixerId` should be removed or need to provide the `$bugFixerId` on $line.